# Antennas- Spacing between Reflectors & Directors in Wavelengths

Tags: antenna, spectrum, spacing, wavelength

I’m building an antenna and I want it to connect to channel 6 on the spectrum allocation chart (2.437 GHz). I’ve calculated the lengths of the reflectors and directors but im just a bit stuck on the spacing between the reflectors and directors.

I’ve came across this table that says the spacing between the reflectors and directors, but it says it in wavelengths. I’m not sure about this measurement means and I was wondering if anyone can help me to shed some light on the spacing between the reflectors and directors from this table.

[image: Table]

Comment: A 2.437 GHz signal has a wavelength of ~123 mm. So one wavelength is 123 mm, 0.5 wavelengths is ~62 mm, etc.

Comment: \$\lambda \times f =3\times 10^8\$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wavelength is the distance travelled by a radio wave in 1 cycle.

Wavelength λ = (300000000/f) metres.

Yagi element dimensions and spacing, which are normally specified in wavelengths, can be converted to metres for the required frequency.